# Getting in shape after age 30+

Tags: muscle-mass, age

I was thinking to start working out to get a nice muscular body, but is it worth it considering I'm 32 years old already? Is it too late?

Comment: Your question seems to me like a clear example of what might be called "age alarmism". 32, in my view, is still very young! In addition to whatever exercise you might take on, consider changing your thinking--you don't want to envision yourself as old before your time. When you're 70, then we can talk.

Answer (score 6):

I really didn't get serious about strength training until thirty, and if you look around you'll see people setting records and being incredibly fit in their 40's (and beyond). A good friend of mine is a spokes-model for a supplement company, and his <5% bodyfat shirtless image is on posters in a lot of supplement chain stores. He's 46 this year.

In short, it's is absolutely not too late. You have, probably, several decades left of strength training.

I'd really recommend starting with a program like Starting Strength. Grab the book, it will the best money you ever spend in fitness.

Answer (score 2):

It's never too late to improve your health and fitness. You may not be able to get the exact physique you want due to reduced testosterone, but, that doesn't mean you can't improve on what you already have. As we age we don't produce the same amount of hormones as we did early in life.  All that means is that fitness gains may be harder to achieve. It does not mean you can't make gains. And more importantly, the improvement in your quality of life as a result of a health and fitness lifestyle certainly outweighs a muscular physique.